# Updating database with dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dynamic, textbox

I'm writing a cart function for a webpage project I have. On the cart page, it checks your cart ID in a cookie, and then gets all of your items in the database. So, every item in the Cart table is dynamically created. On the .aspx page, there is an empty table created. In the codebehind, a new row and cells are created for each item.

I'm having trouble with updating the Quantity of a certain item. For each item in the cart, a textbox and button are dynamically created for the quantity, and updating the quantity. The quantity is set to whatever the quantity is in the database on page load. I can't seem to get the value of the textbox after it has been changed, for example from 1 to 2.

Here's a summary of how the table is populated. I've shortened it a lot, just to show how i'm loading the data into the table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    cartpopulate(cartID);
}

private void cartpopulate(int cartID){
    //for each item in database where cartID is paramater cartID
    //create a row 
    //get the product name, image, price, quantity, options, and make a cell for each
    //calculate total price from quantity and price
    //add in delete and quantity update buttons
```

For ease, lets just assume all the quantites are 1. So, on page_load, it will set all of the quantities to 1. I think my problem is that the following code sets the value of the textbox to whatever the quantity is when it's populated, which would be 1. When you change it to 2 or whatever, the value is already set and the 2 does nothing. The database updating part works, I'm just having trouble getting the second value '2'.

Here's the quantity update code...

```
            if (prod.Quantity == null) { quantitylabel.Value = 1.ToString(); }
            else { quantitylabel.Value = prod.Quantity.ToString() ; }
            quantityinput.ID = "quantity" + i.ToString();
            quantityinput.Width = 20;
            quantityinput.Text = quantitylabel.Value.ToString();
            quantitycell.Controls.Add(quantityinput);
            quantitycell.CssClass="cartitem";
            row.Cells.Add(quantitycell);

            Button btnUpdate = new Button();
            btnUpdate.Text = "Update";
            string arg = quantityinput.Text;
            btnUpdate.CommandName = "update";
            btnUpdate.CommandArgument = arg;
            btnUpdate.Command += (s, e) =>
                {
                    string quanupdate = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
                    int quanint = Convert.ToInt32(quanupdate);
                    prod.Quantity = quanint;
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                    Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
                };
```

I've looked at a few different solutions, but none of them seem to work. Two things I suspect are the issue would be doing something on !IsPostBack, or recreating the dynamically created controls on postback. I'm self-taught at web programming, so I'm not 100% sure how to do that, but I think one of those are the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to use static variables i.e use prod.Quantity as static variable